# GridView OnRowDataBound doesn't Change anything in first Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a gridView in update panel And I set some controls properties in **OnRowDataBound** Event
in **first request** event fires but nothing happen and my controls dosen't Appear

### (if fact controls properties doesn't change!) and in next post back my grid looks ok! there is no problem with panel updating and it didn't solve my problem.

```
protected void GridViewPur1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var isWinner = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblIsWinner")).Visible;
        var auctionPayTimeRemain = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("LBLauctionPayTimeRemain");
        var lblRemaintime = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("LBLRemainTime");
        var IDauctionOrFixPrice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("LBLAorFID");
        var PNLitemAddedToCart = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("PNLitemAddedToCart");
        var idItem = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("LBLidIt")).Text;
        var startTime = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblstartTime")).Text;
        var endDate = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblendDate")).Text;
        var PNLReqToSeller = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("PNLReqToSeller"));

        var btnAddToBasket = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("BTNaddToBasket");
        var btnDelBid = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelBid");
        var btnReqToSeller = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnReqToSeller");
        var imgWinner = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.FindControl("imgWinner");
        var bidDetailIfPayReq = myfunction.getWinPriceIFpayReqFromSLR(IDauctionOrFixPrice.Text, LBLVUID.Value);

        string[] remainTimeAndEnd = RemainTime(IDauctionOrFixPrice.Text);
        string endmin = (int.Parse(startTime) % 100).ToString();//36
        string endhour = ((int.Parse(startTime) / 100) % 100).ToString();//12 
        lblRemaintime.Text = remainTimeAndEnd[0] + "<br/>" + (remainTimeAndEnd[1] == "end" ? (endDate + "<br/>" + endhour + ":" + endmin) : "");


        var isPayReq = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bidDetailIfPayReq.Item1);
        var payReqStartDate = bidDetailIfPayReq.Item2;
        var payReqTotalInHours = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar("SELECT Duration_Hour+(Duration_Day*24) as 'totalInHours' FROM TimingSystem WHERE IDtimingSystem=3") ?? 48;
        var payReqEndDate = payReqStartDate.AddHours(int.Parse(payReqTotalInHours.ToString()));
        TimeSpan payReqRemainDif = payReqEndDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        var payReqPayTimeRemain = !(payReqRemainDif.Days <= 0 && payReqRemainDif.Hours <= 0 && payReqRemainDif.Minutes <= 0 && payReqRemainDif.Seconds <= 0);
        var auctionIsPayable = ((isWinner && Convert.ToBoolean(auctionPayTimeRemain.Text)) || (isPayReq && payReqPayTimeRemain)) && remainTimeAndEnd[1] == "end";

        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["basket"];
        var wasAddedToBasket = false;
        if (cookie != null && cookie[idItem] != null)
            wasAddedToBasket = true;
        else
            wasAddedToBasket = false;

        var addToBasketReqVisible = false;


        var isReqable = false;
        var hasReq = false;
        var acceptedText = "";

        if (isWinner && !Convert.ToBoolean(auctionPayTimeRemain.Text) && remainTimeAndEnd[1] == "end")
        {
            var query2 = "select isAccepted,IDbuyerPaymentRequest from BuyerPaymentRequest where IDitem= " + idItem + " and UID= " + LBLVUID.Value;
            DataTable dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Constants.ConnectionString, CommandType.Text, query2).Tables[0];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var isAccepted = dt.Rows[i]["isAccepted"].ToString();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(isAccepted))
                    {
                        acceptedText = "request sent";
                    }
                    if (isAccepted == "False")
                    {
                        acceptedText = "<img src='/images/deleteIcon.gif' />";
                    }
                    if (isAccepted == "True")
                    {
                        acceptedText = "";
                        addToBasketReqVisible = true;
                    }
                    hasReq = true;
                }
            }
            else if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
            {
                isReqable = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            acceptedText = "";
        }


        var isVisibleDelBidBtn = false;
        var showWinnerImage = false;

        if (isWinner && remainTimeAndEnd[1] == "end")
        {
            showWinnerImage = true;
            //mydatarow["addToBasket"] = "<a href='" + myfunction.itemAddressReturn(IDitem, itemName) + "' target='_top' style='font-size: 10pt; font-weight:bold;'>buy</a>";
        }
        else if (remainTimeAndEnd[1] == "end")
        {
            isVisibleDelBidBtn = true;
        }


        btnAddToBasket.Visible = auctionIsPayable && !wasAddedToBasket || (addToBasketReqVisible && !wasAddedToBasket);
        PNLitemAddedToCart.Visible = (auctionIsPayable && wasAddedToBasket) || (isReqable && wasAddedToBasket);
        btnReqToSeller.Visible = isReqable;
        PNLReqToSeller.Visible = hasReq;
        PNLReqToSeller.Text = acceptedText;
        btnDelBid.Visible = isVisibleDelBidBtn;
        imgWinner.Visible = showWinnerImage;
        UpdatePanelPur1.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `OnRowDataBound` code? It may help to know what is happening in there.

Comment: this is my code. thanks